# STM32f0 Low power mode

Tags: stm32, low-power, stm32f0

I have a problem with low power mode on **STM32F030F4** (header board **stm32f030f4p6** ). 
When I try to put them in Stop mode they still consume about **5.6mA** which is too much ( it should be about **500uA**). 
I put it to Stop mode through:

**`PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_Regulator_LowPower, PWR_STOPEntry_WFI);`**

I don't do any **RCC on GPIO** configuration. Also I don't have any external devices connected to STM, any pullup resistors etc.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

My code :

```
    SystemClock_Config();

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

      /*Configure GPIO pins : PF0 PF1 */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode =  GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
             GPIO_InitStruct.Speed =GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);


      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3 
                              |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7 
                              |GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
         GPIO_InitStruct.Speed =GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed =GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_All,GPIO_PIN_RESET); 

         __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_DISABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();

while (1)
{

    HAL_Delay(1000);
  HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON,PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);


}
```

[image]

Comment: do you have any specification for this. datasheet shows 48uA @ 85degC. If any internal pull-ups/pull-downs are there can you enable them and check...

Comment: You may need to disable any pullups

Comment: @ScottSeidman all pin's already set  'GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;'

Comment: Inputs must not float during sleep. They either need to be high or low outputs with no load OR inputs with pullup or pulldown.  A floating input can cause substantial and varying current drain.

Comment: Data sheet link ...?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon data Sheet http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/a4/5d/0b/0e/87/c4/4d/71/DM00088500.pdf/files/DM00088500.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00088500.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All pin's already set
>   'GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG; GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;'

I/O pins **must not** be set as floating inputs  during sleep.
They need to be any of

- high or low outputs with no load or
- inputs with pullup or pulldown.

An input pulled to either rail will cause minimal current drain. Sometimes one or other is lower - the data sheet should tell you.

A floating input can (and often does) cause substantial and varying current drain. The transistor high/low pair connected to the input pin can be biased to an in between state so that "shoot through" current flow from Vdd to ground.

---

Check all peripherals (again :-) ).

Measure voltages across ALL remaining resistors.
All should be ~= 0V in STOP mode.

---

There are various implementations and you do not AFAICS identify your.
The diagram below [from here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/YS-39-STM32F030F4P6-Core-Board-Development-Board-With-ARM-CORTEX-M0-Core-New-/131576026314) is typical.
Red ellipses show "just maybe" current paths.

[image]

[Another](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8A_pAms-qTQ/U-OUvzkE3-I/AAAAAAAAAFM/14_9ED0Abdc/s1600/stm32f030f4p6.BMP)  - less choices [from here](http://erkankarakas.blogspot.co.nz/2014/08/stm32f030f4p6-deneme-kart.html)

Comment: In my experience the STM32 GPIO structure is surprisingly different and setting them to analog mode without pull-resistors results in lowest current consumption. This is reflected by the fact that in the new ultra low power L4xx series the analog mode is the startup configuration of the pins.

Comment: tanx for answer :) ,i checked all  resistors voltages **values ( ~= zero)** in  stop mode

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are measuring the quiescent current of the voltage regulator on top of the MCU stop current.

If [this schematic](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/STM32F030-Dev-Board/STM32F030F4P6.pdf) is the correct one, there is a LM1117-3.3 voltage regulator on board.

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf#page6) for the LM1117 shows a typical quiescent current of 5mA.

So you have a typical 5mA plus a typical 500µA which results in a typical 5.5mA. Pretty close to what you are measuring.

Maybe you can try to just measure the difference between active and stop current and see if that difference corresponds to the difference calculated from values in the datasheet.

EDIT1:

I'd also suggest to perform `SystemClock_Config()` at the start of the program and not at the end of the `while()` loop. The content of the registers is preserved during stop of the controller.

I must say that I am a bit curious what a microcontroller is supposed to do when it is not connected to anything.

EDIT2:

I was thinking that the debugger/programmer might interfere with your measurement, but if you disconnect the SWDIO and SWCLK line and reset the controller it should be fine. The debugger can enable some internal debugging peripherals which might consume additional current. Resetting or power cycling will reset those peripherals, so they are inactive.

At this point I am at a loss what might cause this current draw. Just another idea: check that there are no solder connections where they shouldn't be. I managed several times to create a solder bridge which was small enough to not be a short circuit but strong enough to cause a significant current flow.

Comment: tanx for the answer, i use two battery **AAA (1.5V each)** for Power supply board and, i need my MCU live for **two months** :) ,i dont use usb pwr (5v) , if the remove **lm1117** on the board، **this problem will be solved**?

Comment: @qasem it should be. But I would check if my answer is right (measuring the difference) before removing it. I don't know how you program the chip, so maybe you need to keep it until you have programmed the final program.

Comment: Please tell me the solution, I finished project, just I have a problem in stop mode :)|  current consumption in   active mode = 9 ma | stop mode = 5.5 ma

Comment: @qasem that seems a reasonable number, so remove the LM1117 and see if it helps.

Comment: now  remove  **lm1117** on the board ,but still take  current over 1 ma **[ value now active mode 5.5 - stop mode 3.35]**

Comment: @qasem I've edited my answer based on the additional code you posted. I've previously measured the current of the stopmode of the STM32F4xx and it was around 10µA to 110µA depending on settings, so it should be possible to push the F030 down to that level as well.

Comment: i tested any samples ,and change line for this method **SystemClock_Config**,but not change state :) tanx for your help

Comment: @Arsenal The `HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON,PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);` function calls the `__WFI()` if the second param is `PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI` and calls     `__SEV();` and `__WFE();` otherwise.

Comment: @BenceKaulics ah I misunderstood the documentation, okay so scrap that. I'm not using the ST HAL, so I'm not firm in that regard.

Comment: @BenceKaulics Yes that's right  call _wfi method in background ;)

Comment: @qasem do you have the debugger/programmer connected while measuring the current?

Comment: @Arsenal no i unplug pin's [clk ,swdio] from board but use pin [3.3 and gnd] from st-link debugger

Comment: @qasem this is really getting strange. Only thing which comes to mind now: do you perform a power cycle? (unplug the 3.3V and plug it back on)

Comment: @Arsenal see image board in question (from top page) Red and black ellipses show pin used :)

Comment: @qasem it's not the pins you use - do you reset the device after programming it disconnecting the power cable and putting it back on?

Comment: @Arsenal yes i click button reset after programming, but i use only this pin's plz More Explain !!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your board has any led which gets used (and most seems to have, at least the led for indicating power), it is going to take some current.  That may be the reason you're getting that level of current.

Comment: tanx for answer , i already removed all led on the board